# Stubbing File.exists? in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test the `else` branch of the following ruby code:

```ruby
SCHEMA_SOURCE = if File.exist? SCHEMA_FILENAME
                  SCHEMA_FILENAME
                else
                  ContentfulApi::Http
                end
```

I cannot find a way to mock the non-existence of the file `SCHEMA_FILENAME`. Here are the simplified versions of the test I have tried, and the error:

```ruby
it 'fails to find file when it does not exist' do
  allow(File).to receive(:exists?).and_return(false)
  expect(File.exist?(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)).to be_falsey
end
```

```ruby
it 'fails to find file when it does not exist' do
  allow(File).to receive(:exists?).with(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)\
                                  .and_return(false)
  expect(File.exist?(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)).to be_falsey
end
```

These both fail with the error

> expected: falsey value
> got: true

```ruby
it 'fails to find file when it does not exist' do
  File.stub(:exists?) { false }
  expect(File.exist?(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)).to be_falsey
end
```

```ruby
it 'fails to find file when it does not exist' do
  File.stub!(:exists?).with(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)\
                      .and_return(false)
  expect(File.exist?(ContentfulApi::SCHEMA_FILENAME)).to be_falsey
end
```

These both fail with the error

> undefined method `stub' for File:Class

My first two attempts follow the example in the [Method Stubs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) documentation, though there may be a distinction between classes and objects that is not explored in that documentation. (Though classes *are* objects in Ruby, right?)

The second two attempts follow [older documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs).

How should I stub `File.exist? SCHEMA_FILENAME` so that it returns `false` even though the file does actually exist?

N.B. The approaches in these similar questions do not work:

- [rspec to stub several File.exists? calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627007/575530)
- [Rspec -- need to stub File.open that gets called in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16967737/575530)
- [rspec undefined method stub for model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15779257/575530)
- [how to reset expectations on a mocked class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25308667/575530)
- [How do I stub out a specific file with rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9247095/575530)
- [Can't stub things with Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18686491/575530)
- [rspec 3 - stub a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25066699/575530)

Comment: On a side note I don't think this is a good use of a constant - constants should just be straight up assignment. So if you have to write a test for it then it should not be a constant. Make it a class method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mocking `File.exists?` and calling `File.exist?`.

Note that if you have `verify_partial_doubles` set, and you should, RSpec won't allow you to mock a method which does not exist.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end

RSpec.describe File do
  it 'cannot mock a method whcih does not exist' do
    allow(File).to receive(:dslkfjalk).and_return(true)
  end
end
```

```
Failures:

  1) File cannot mock a method whcih does not exist
     Failure/Error: allow(File).to receive(:dslkfjalk).and_return(true)
       File does not implement: dslkfjalk
```

But `File` does have both `exist?` and `exists?` methods. [`File.exists?` is deprecated](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/File.html#method-c-exists-3F) and removed from the documentation, but I guess it still... exists.